# C# | Catch exception from a dynamically loaded dll

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to write a C# (WPF - not that it matters in that context) application that loads a DLL dynamically using this code:

```
private Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);
    }
```

Loading the dll works fine and also using it works.

The problem is - when I try catching an exception when calling a function on that dynamically loaded DLL it is not caught in my application

Note: The dynamically loaded dll was also written by me so I know for a fact that an exception occurs

The try/catch section looks like that

```
                try
                {
                    result = aseInstance.Compile();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
```

I also tried using the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

but didn't help..

One more thing that might be worth mentioning - useInstance is a dynamic
I don't want my code to have to "know" which class it is loading so I'm using dynamic

If i do the same using references everything works and the exception is caught

I'd love some help here!
Thanks

Comment: I assume `aseInstance` is an object retrieved from the assembly you loaded?

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry for not mentioning in the post

Comment: Any chance you can create a [mcve], basically post the code for a small "both sides of the conversation" type of thing, basically a small piece of code that loads an assembly, obtains an object from it, and then calls a method on it, as well as the code in that loaded assembly? I would just like to see that there's not something we're missing here.

Comment: I created a small test solution here - https://github.com/lvk-stackoverflow/61225849 - it has 3 projects, an assembly that will be loaded with a class, and one project using references and one using Assembly.LoadFile, can you see if you can muck around with it to try to see either what is different (you mention C# 4 for instance, old .net version perhaps?), or what you or I missed? To note, the code in my solution works as expected so I am assuming there has to be some differences. You will need to compile to debug for the dynamic project to find the assembly (hardcoded assumptions)

Comment: Actually when I tried making a small example it also worked so I guess it has something to do with my specific code within the dll im loading.. I'll poke around there. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!